# How to send array parameter to remote over dblink in oracle

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have several instances: dbA, dbB, dbC.., then i want to query data from local and link to other instance over dblink, and expected is **l_ids** will be send to remote site cause **l_ids** is ligh and **table@dbA** is numerous, just as followering:

```
DECLARE
   out_row_data       SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_ids              UDT_TBL_NUMBER;  -- TABLE OF NUMBER(10)
   l_sql VARCHAR2(18000);
BEGIN
   l_sql := 'SELECT * FROM tableX@dbA 
   WHERE column IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(:l_ids));'
   
   OPEN out_row_data FOR l_sql
   USING l_ids;
END;/
```

But execution plan shows data of tableX fetched first, then join with table(l_ids).
Another try, using driving_site hint to specify it, but didn't work either:

```
DECLARE
   out_row_data       SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_ids              UDT_TBL_NUMBER;  -- TABLE OF NUMBER(10)
   l_sql VARCHAR2(18000);
BEGIN
   l_sql := 'SELECT  /*+ MONITOR driving_site(X) */ * FROM TABLE(:l_ids) GIDS
   LEFT JOIN tableX@dbA X ON GIDS.column_value = X.column;'
   
   OPEN out_row_data FOR l_sql
   USING l_ids;
END;/
```

I have no idea now, above statement all process successfully, but execution plan aren't as expected.

Can someone help me or need more info? :(

**Update**

I think if driving_site is work, the **tableX REMOTE** operation shouldn't exist.

**Streamline dynamic sqltext:**

```
  l_sql := '
    WITH matched_Y AS (
        SELECT *
          FROM tableY@dbB
    ), matched_X AS (
        SELECT /*+ MONITOR no_merge(X) */
               column1
              ,sum(column2)
          FROM 
          (
              SELECT /*+ MONITOR driving_site(RX) DRSITE */ * FROM 
              TABLE(:ids) GIDS
              LEFT JOIN tableX@dbA RX
              ON GIDS.column_value = RX.column1
          ) X
            LEFT JOIN TABLE(:currency_table) ct 
                ON column3 >= ct.column3 
        GROUP BY column1
    ), matched_X2 AS (
        SELECT *
          FROM (matched_X)
        GROUP BY column1
    )
    SELECT *
      FROM matched_Y g
           LEFT JOIN matched_X2 w ON g.column1 = w.column1
    ORDER BY g.column4 DESC';
```

**Execution plan**

```
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |IN-OUT|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |       |       |       |       |  3141 (100)|          |        |      |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                            |       | 11790 |  9936K|    10M|  3141   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                   |       | 11790 |  9936K|       |  1001   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   3 |    VIEW                                   |       |     1 |   130 |       |    60   (2)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY                         |       |     1 |    96 |       |    60   (2)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |       |    20 |  1920 |       |    59   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   6 |       VIEW                                |       |     1 |    94 |       |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|*  7 |        FILTER                             |       |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |
|*  8 |         HASH JOIN                         |       |     1 |   109 |       |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   9 |          REMOTE                           | tableX|     1 |   107 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | DBLIN~ | R->S |
|  10 |          COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH|       |   100 |   200 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|* 11 |       COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH   |       |    20 |    40 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|* 12 |    VIEW                                   |       | 11790 |  8439K|       |   941   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|  13 |     REMOTE                                |       |       |       |       |            |          | DBLIN~ | R->S |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
```

Comment: can you show execution plans ?

Answer (score 0):

In a true distributed query, the optimization is done on the sending site. Because your local site may not have access to the CBO statistics on the remote site.

The `driving_site` hint forces query execution to be done at a different site than the initiating instance. This is done when the remote table is much larger than the local table and you want the work (join, sorting) done remotely to save the back-and-forth network traffic.

Your plan is behaving correctly, from the perspective of the driving site, and without proper knowledge of the filter operations done by the optimizer ( this part of the plan is not in your post ), I would suggest to try and get rid of the `nested loops outer` produced by the left join, to see whether a `hash join` can behave better.

```
WITH matched_Y AS (
    SELECT /*+ materialize */ *
      FROM tableY@dbB
), matched_X AS (
    SELECT /*+ MONITOR no_merge(X) use_hash(ct,x) */
           column1
          ,sum(column2)
      FROM 
      (
          SELECT /*+ MONITOR driving_site(RX) DRSITE */ * FROM 
          TABLE(:ids) GIDS
          LEFT JOIN tableX@dbA RX
          ON GIDS.column_value = RX.column1
      ) X
        LEFT JOIN TABLE(:currency_table) ct 
            ON column3 >= ct.column3 
    GROUP BY column1
), matched_X2 AS (
    SELECT *
      FROM (matched_X)
    GROUP BY column1
)
SELECT *
  FROM matched_Y g
       LEFT JOIN matched_X2 w ON g.column1 = w.column1
ORDER BY g.column4 DESC
```

Comment: Hi @Roberto Hernandez, thank for your answer, its really the reason i use driving_site hint, and the alias wrong is clerical error. :(
I have fixed, and updated the execution plan.

Comment: @ClarkMiy, I don't see any issue in the plan. It is using driving site the remote table ( RX ). I only see an issue because of the NESTED LOOPS OUTER.

Comment: the remote is only telling you that the object is not local

Comment: but the operation *8
 8 - access("RX"."COLUMN1"=VALUE(KOKBF$))
, it seems hash join with RX and  l_ids in the local site

Comment: indeed, but the 5 is not. Anyway, the query takes too much or is fast ?

Comment: or how can i ensure driving site is working from plan, it have some feature?
i use it in another simple case, it wouldnt have "remote operator" in local's plan and remote's plan apear "remote operator".

Comment: the root issue is query too slow, so i want to send the ids array to remote site to avoid big data query in remote

Comment: 5 seems operation with currency_table by left join

Comment: @ClarkMiy, I updated the answer, but it is very difficult without understanding where the query is taking time. For that we would need a report from `sql monitor`